# Fabric Go chaincode install error: Error: error getting chaincode bytes: 'go list'

Tags: docker, go, hyperledger-fabric

Im trying to install the golang chaincode inside the peer docker container and Im getting the following error. The installation worked fine with the nodeJs chaincode.

```
volumes:
  - ./msps/peer4.org1/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
  - ../go-chaincode/dataCC:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/org1/dataCC
  - ./peer4:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/files
  -  peer4.org1.com:/var/hyperledger/production
```

Where the `go-chaincode/dataCC` directory contains the go module of the chaincode.

**command**

```
peer lifecycle chaincode package $DATA_CHAINCODETAR_FILE --path $CORE_PEER_CHAINCODE_ID_PATH  --lang golang --label datacc_1
```

**Logs**

```
2020-08-08 02:54:16.263 UTC [bccsp] GetDefault -> DEBU 002 Before using BCCSP, please call InitFactories(). Falling back to bootBCCSP.
2020-08-08 02:54:16.270 UTC [main] InitCmd -> DEBU 003 peer lifecycle chaincode package does not need to init crypto
```

**Error:**

```
error getting chaincode bytes: 'go list' failed: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH
```

**docker-container**

```
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer # go list
sh: go: not found
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the issue and was able to successfully install and instantiate chaincode. Now, this might not be the best way to resolve this, but it certainly worked for me.

- Go inside your peer/cli container using the command `docker exec -it container_name bash`(`bash`/`sh` according to the container's OS).
- Install the go binary from [here](https://golang.org/doc/install) and follow all the installation instructions. Make sure to check `go` is installed by following the example in the attached link.
- Run `mkdir -p /root/go/src` and copy your chaincode folder inside this directory.
- Install/Package/Instantiate your chaincode.

Make sure to set the environment variable `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH` to the admin's `msp` directory before installing/packaging the chaincode. The default path is `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`.

Try this approach and see if it works for you.

I'll update this answer whenever I find something useful or a better solution.

Comment: Hi Kartik, thanks for answering the question. The issue got resolved after I packaged it with the cli container. Looks like all the other languages chaincode can be packaged through peer container except golang. The golang can be only be packaged through cli

Comment: You can add your own answer here to help the people who face this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Execute below commands and then retry to deploy chaincode:

```
$go env GOPROXY=https://goproxy.io,direct
$go env GO111MODULE=on
```

if above command doesn't run properly then execute below commands.

```
$ export GO111MODULE=on
$ export GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn
```

for reference :  https://goproxy.cn/